# What happens to thermodynamic state functions when they are scaled by a state variable?

Tags: thermodynamics

When a state function like the internal energy is divided by the number of particles (which is not constant), does it stay a state function or does it become a process-dependent function?

Comment: Which case of a non-constant number of particles are you thinking about?

Comment: When two ideal gases are mixing

Comment: It is not obvious why or in what circumstances the number of particles is not constant.